# Max Sum of All K consecutive sub arrays from 1 to n of an array using sliding window

Tags: arrays, c, max, sliding-window, sub-array

## This is my code and it does well for positive numbers given in the array but when one of the input      numbers is negative it doesn't work

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);  // Getting the length of array
    int arr[n];       // array of n length
    int sum[n];       // a sum array for finding the biggest sub arrays
    int max = -50;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);  // getting arrays elements
    }
    for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum[i] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                sum[i] = sum[i] + arr[j + i];
                if (sum[i] > max) {
                    max = sum[i];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d", max);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

i think the max=-50 might be the problem but it is there for comparing
sums so if they were bigger it would put them as the new max

first input is the length of the array

Example Input:

```
4
3
7
-5
1
```

Expected Output:

```
7
10
5
6
```

Observed output:

```
7
10
10
10
```

Comment: Considering that the code you show won't even build, any behavior is purely speculative. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to show us a proper [mre] (please *copy-paste* it). And read [the formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Right before the line `sum[i] = sum[i] + arr[j + i];` you can add `printf("%d <= %d ?\n", n, j + i); fflush(stdout);` and see if you see anything fishy. If `j + i >= n` you are accessing `arr` out of bounds.

Comment: Your code fails to reinitialize `max` for each length (each `k`). Your code tests `sum[i]>max` after each addition to `sum[i]` while iterating over the elements in a subsequence instead of once after completing computing `sum[i]` for a given subsequence. Your code lets `j+i` run beyond the end of the array; it needs to limit `i` based on `k`.